# Input tag placed inside quotes and being rendered as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an input tag that's being rendered inside quotation marks in the dom so it's displaying as a string.

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="choking-hazard">
  <%= f.label :choking_hazard, :class => 'featuredLabel' do %>
    <%= t '.small_object', :f_check_box => (f.check_box :choking_hazard) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

```
small_object: "%{f_check_box}"
```

Any idea what would be causing this? I'm not too familiar with rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume f_check_box is a variable in translation with key .small_object.
its the result of translation is a string which is rendered in double quotes.
use

```
<%= raw(t '.small_object', :f_check_box => (f.check_box :choking_hazard)) %>
```

or

```
<%= (t '.small_object', :f_check_box => (f.check_box :choking_hazard)).html_safe %>
```

Comment: Thanks, .html_safe fixed it.